# Client-side cookies turning up as blank string in simple HTML/vanilla JS page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to get some practice working with cookies. I am trying to practice this by creating a very simple page where the user chooses either light or dark mode. When they click the button, I save their selection within a cookie (I know that localStorage would also work, but I want to play around with cookies).

I've done some searching on stack overflow and most people's questions are for more complex situations with cookies involving server-side issues. Though some answers have mentioned problems with cookies being saved on localhost. I'm simply opening my html page in my browser: `file:///Users/wl/projects/cookies/index.html`. Will cookies not be set on a local file such as this one?

Is there a way for me to practice working with cookies on the client-side locally?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="container">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <div class="selectTheme">
      <h1>Pick a theme:</h1>
      <button type="button" id="lightMode" class="btn btn-light">Light Mode</button>
      <button type="button" id="darkMode" class="btn btn-danger dark">Dark Mode</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

main.js (all of the console.logs come up blank, but I think they should return the cookie string that I just set)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  document.querySelector("#lightMode").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.cookie="theme=light; maxAge=500000000"
    console.log(document.cookie)
  })
  document.querySelector("#darkMode").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.cookie="theme=dark; maxAge=500000000"
    console.log(document.cookie)
  })
  
})

console.log(document.cookie)
```

Comment: Most browsers do not set cookies for file protocol. Run a local server.

Comment: Why are servers so necessary for cookies? Since cookies are data saved to a users computer I feel like it should work on file protocol. I understand that in most cases they are used to identify/authenticate users and such and those use cases require passing the cookies back and forth. But I can also see a use case for saving user preference locally without saving that on a server. Am I missing something about cookies?

Comment: Because file protocol has different security than http. If you would have been developing 15 years ago things were different. Run a local server. It is exactly the same as saving to a local file. Every web developer runs a server.... localhost.... IDES have plugins that also do it.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I just kicked up a local server and it works as expected now! I was just worried I was misunderstanding something about how cookies work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user12457151 Don't forget to mark this question as answered :)

Comment: @GetFuzzy thanks for the reminder! Looks like I have to post an actual answer and come back to it in 5 hours though to mark as asnwered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which @epascarello helped me with in the comments was to run a local server. Cookies just don't work on file protocol for security reasons. I used npm http-server to do it super easily.